# Выполнение действия при записи регистра на modbus tcp сервере

Tags: python, modbus

Друзья, добрый вечер. Есть modbus-tcp сервер, написанный на pymodbus библиотеке питона. Внешнее устройство по своему алгоритму делает запись регистра на этом сервере. Как обработать изменение этого регистра, чтоб по этому изменению выполнять какое-нибудь действие, например отправлять сообщение в чат-бот?